# What does the == operator actually do on a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider:

```
>>> a = {'foo': {'bar': 3}}
>>> b = {'foo': {'bar': 3}}
>>> a == b
True
```

According to the python doc, [you can indeed use](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) the `==` operator on dictionaries.

What is actually happening here? Is Python recursively checking each element of the dictionaries to ensure equality? Is it making sure the keys are identically matched, and the values are also identically matched?

Is there documentation that specifies exactly what `==` on a dictionary means? Or whether I have to implement my own version of checking for equality?

(If the `==` operator works, why aren't dicts hashable? That is, why can't I create a set() of dicts, or use a dict as a dictionary key?)

Comment: dicts aren't hashable because they are mutable and their data is sensitive to past states. It would be easy to have two dicts that have equal states, but unequal hashes due to the history of a dict (containing more dummy entries)

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: you could easily ignore the dummy entries; that's not an issue. The mutability is a huge issue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Python is recursively checking each element of the dictionaries to ensure equality. See the [C  `dict_equal()` implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6f535c725b27/Objects/dictobject.c#l1839), which checks each and every key and value (provided the dictionaries are the same length); if dictionary `b` has the same key, then a `PyObject_RichCompareBool` tests if the values match too; this is essentially a recursive call.

Dictionaries are not hashable because their [`__hash__` attribute is set to `None`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), and most of all they are *mutable*, which is disallowed when used as a dictionary key.

If you were to use a dictionary as a key, and through an existing reference then change the key, then that key would no longer slot to the same position in the hash table. Using another, equal dictionary (be it equal to the unchanged dictionary or the changed dictionary) to try and retrieve the value would now no longer work because the wrong slot would be picked, or the key would no longer be equal.

Answer (score 20):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted
>   (key, value) lists compare equal .[[5]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id24) Outcomes other than equality are
>   resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined. [[6]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id25)

Footnote [[5]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id24):

> The implementation computes this efficiently, without constructing
>   lists or sorting.

Footnote [[6]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id25):

> Earlier versions of Python used lexicographic comparison of the sorted
>   (key, value) lists, but this was very expensive for the common case of
>   comparing for equality. An even earlier version of Python compared
>   dictionaries by identity only, but this caused surprises because
>   people expected to be able to test a dictionary for emptiness by
>   comparing it to {}.

Comment: Note that the actual implementation uses dictionary order for the left-hand operand, and bails out first if the number of keys differs, then as soon as a key is not present in the other dict or the associated values do not compare equal.

Answer (score 11):

The dictionaries are equal if they have the same keys and the same values for each corresponding key.

See some examples:

```
dict(a=1, b=2) == dict(a=2, b=1)
False

dict(a=1, b=2) == dict(a=1, b=2, c=0)
False

dict(a=1, b=2) == dict(b=2, a=1)
True
```