# Is it safe to assume that == operator will always work to compare dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

[What does the == operator actually do on a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217225/what-does-the-operator-actually-do-on-a-python-dictionary)

From the question above , == operator will compare two dictionaries keys and their corresponding values. But I see in many places in code where the keys and values are iterated to check equality of dictionaries.

I wanted to check only the equality condition on two dictionaries.

Comment: I dont get what you are asking. It seems you know what the equal operator does for dictionaries, what else are you asking about?

Comment: I think the interesting question is, _why_ are people iterating key/value pairs manually? Possibly they don't know that == is safe, or maybe they're doing something more exotic than checking regular equality. I'd love to see some examples of these "many places in code".

Comment: Where exactly, under what circumstances and in whose code?

Comment: I have seen it my organization code base. Also refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: I am not an expert in python that is why this question.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your organization why they do it that way. Also, your "refer here" question is about counting the number of matched elements, so it's a different thing.

Comment: Well look in the version control logs, find out who wrote it and ask them, we can't tell you why they made that choice.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply: yes, the `==` operator is safe on the built-in Python dictionaries and should always work.