# What is difference between comparing dictionaries directly and comparing them after converting them to a set?

Tags: python-3.x

So I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217225/what-does-the-operator-actually-do-on-a-python-dictionary#) that indicates that comparing two dictionaries with ==, Python will look through each key of two dictionaries and check if each value is the same. I am writing some unit tests and I want to check to make sure that some data I am pulling from a website matches some that I previously pulled in postman, and saved to a text file. Why does comparing the dictionaries below return false, but returning those same dictionaries as sets, return true?

```
    records = self.get_raw_records(form_id) #this pulls the data
    with open("Sample Pull Data.txt", "r") as file:
        contents = json.load(file) #this is the data I already pulled
        print(contents[0]==records[0]) #false
        print(set(contents[0]) == set(records[0])) #true
        file.close()
```

I noticed that the order of keys varied, but accoriding to the linked question, or more importantly from the 3.6 [docs:](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) that shouldn't matter.

> Mappings (instances of dict) compare equal if and only if they have
>   equal (key, value) pairs. Equality comparison of the keys and values
>   enforces reflexivity.

Comment: Doesn't `set(dict)` just make a set of the dict's keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` only contains the keys from the dictionary - not the keys and values. As the docs say, dict comparison tests *if they have equal (key, value) pairs.*

So doing `set` comparison is equivalent to doing `dict.keys()` comparison (and in fact `keys()` can be used as sets in python 3).

```
a = {1:1}
b = {1:2}
a == b
# False
set(a) == set(b)
# True
a.keys() == b.keys()
# True
set(a) == a.keys()
# True
```