# Efficient way to find *ordered* intersection of dictionaries starting at top (or an arbitrary index)?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I'm looking for an efficient way to find the intersection of two Python dictionaries where order matters, starting at the top. In other words, loop through the dictionaries and once their keys or values differ, stop. I think this is clearest with some examples.

- The intersection of `{a: 1, b: 0}` and `{a: 1, b: 1}` is obviously `{a: 1}`.
- The intersection of `{a: 1, b: 0, c: 1}` and `{a: 1, c: 1, b: 0}` is just `{a: 1}` since order matters.
- The intersection of `{a: 1, b: 0}` and `{b: 0, c: 1}` is empty because they don't start on the same key.

I have the following function which works, but I'm wondering if there's an easier/faster way.

```
def find_ordered_intersection(d0, d1):
    d1keys = list(d1.keys())
    intersection = {}
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d0.items()):
        if (k == d1keys[i]) and (v == d1[k]):
            intersection.update({k:v})
        else:
            return intersection
```

p.s. I'm having a hard time succinctly describing my goal. If anyone has edits, please feel free.

Comment: This problem might not be well-defined because dictionaries do not have a guaranteed order.

Comment: Is the code you have shown too slow?

Comment: But if you loop through them, they'll always have the same order, no? So my function above will work?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's not terribly slow, I just thought there might be a faster or easier solution with set methods or something like that. If not, then that's a good answer too!

Comment: You also checking that the values are equal. Right?

Comment: @mkrieger For versions of python 3.6+ the order of keys is [guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) and no longer just an implementation detail.

Comment: @mkrieger1: The guaranteed order of dictionaries nowadays is insertion order.

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes checking values (that's what `v == d1[k]` should do)

Comment: @DragonBobZ yes I know. But there wasn't a Python version specified in the question and it isn't universally true. Plus, what I think I also meant was that dictionaries still aren't sequence types, meaning for example that they don't support indexing or slicing, and, [as far as I understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217225/what-does-the-operator-actually-do-on-a-python-dictionary), differently ordered dictionaries might still compare equal, which poses the interesting problem that `a == b` might not imply `f(a) == f(b)`. I'm not sure if all this is relevant here.

Comment: @mkrieger Your caveat and my response are all good information to have in this comment chain for the asker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with relying in the insertion order, you could do the following, using [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#func-dict):

```
from itertools import takewhile


def intersection(a, b):
    return dict(kb for ka, kb in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(a.items(), b.items())))


print(intersection({'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}))
print(intersection({'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}))
print(intersection({'a': 1, 'b': 0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1}))
print(intersection({'a': 1, 'b': 0, }, {'b': 0, 'c': 1}))
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 1}
{'a': 1}
{'a': 1}
{}
```

Comment: Care to explain @DragonBobZ?

Comment: I don't think this works for my question (though my question might have been unclear). I want to stop execution once any pair doesn't match. So, `{a: 1, b: 0, c: 1}` and `{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}` should return `{a: 1}` not `{a: 1, c: 1}`.

Comment: @Dani Maseji the intersection of `{0:1, 3:4, 4:3}, {0:2, 4:3, 3:4}` should be `{3:4, 4:3}` but your function returns `{}`

Comment: @DragonBobZ No, it should not, see the question

Comment: It seems I misunderstood that the spacing and position of keys matters.

Comment: Oooh `takewhile`. This is what I was looking for. Thanks so much @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier to understand.

```
def find_ordered_intersection(d0, d1):
    d0keys = list(d0.keys())
    d1keys = list(d1.keys())
    size = min(len(d0), len(d1))

    dic = {}

    for i in range(size):
        key0 = d0keys[i]
        key1 = d1keys[i]
        if key0 != key1:
            break
        elif d0[key0] != d1[key1]:
            break
        else:
            dic[key0] = d0[key0]
    return dic
```

Comment: Definitely clearer to understand. Though probably the same speed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_ordered_intersection(d0, d1):
    intersection = {tpl[0][0]: tpl[0][1] for tpl in zip(d0.items(), d1.items()) if (tpl[0][0] == tpl[1][0]) and (tpl[0][1] == tpl[1][1])}
    return intersection
 
#The intersection of {a: 1, b: 0} and {a: 1, b: 1} is obviously {a: 1}.
#The intersection of {a: 1, b: 0, c: 1} and {a: 1, c: 1, b: 0} is just {a: 1} since order matters.
#The intersection of {a: 1, b: 0} and {b: 0, c: 1} is empty because they don't start on the same key.

d0 = {'a': 1, 'b': 0} 
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
print(find_ordered_intersection(d0, d1))

d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
d3 = {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 0}
print(find_ordered_intersection(d2, d3))

d4 = {'a': 1, 'b': 0}
d5 = {'b': 0, 'c': 1} 
print(find_ordered_intersection(d4, d5))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1}
{'a': 1}
{}
```